# Upload files of more than2 GB from EC2 to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, large-files

I'm working on a rails project and am using aws-sdk 1.66.0. I want to upload a folder to s3 but as i cant actually do that, i'm grabbing the zip file and unzipping it on my EC2 server. Once the files are unzipped, i'm recursively uploading them to the S3. [This](http://www.avitzurel.com/blog/2013/12/03/upload-folder-to-s3-recursively/) article depicts something similar and i have followed it.

All is working great for files with 250 MB and 350 MB. However when trying to upload a much larger file of around  2 GB, i am facing error. I see the file being uploaded to the EC2 successfully but the same is not getting uploaded to S3. Sometimes, i see the logs appear indicating the file is being uploaded to S3 but the file doesn't actually get uploaded.

At other times, there are no logs.

I'm not sure what i'm missing or what extra things needs to be done for large file uploads.

I'll be grateful for any help. Please let me know any details are required. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you should maybe try to use a [multi part upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu-ruby-sdk.html)

Comment: @FrédéricHenri, I have implemented and my files are uploding in parts to S3.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri, you were indeed right about using the multi-part in AWS. My initial code did send the file in parts and i thought that its no different. Though i'm not sure how, may be thats what S3 does for large files. However, i ended up using the actual multi-part uploading and it worked like a charm. If you could post the same as the answer, i would accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I think you can make your own answer with your updated code, it can help more people than pointing them to the doc

Comment: I appreciate it. Thanks. Will soon be posting a full framed answer. Cheers :)